# How can I track down the bottlenecks in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-performance

Given a complex multitab Google spreadsheet, what tools and methodologies are there to find what is slowing down my sheet execution?

I'm seeing behaviour where the ribbon that shows recalc progress will instantly start at 1/3, then take up to a minute to finish, then restart at a different point, take a few seconds to calculate, for 3 to 8 times, with a total calculation time of 1 to 4 minutes.

Are there audit tools that will look at the entire spreadsheet?

Are there methodologies to organize a spreadsheet to reduce multi-pass recalculation.

Comment: The second question makes this post too broad and primarily opinion-based. Please edit it to make it fit the guidelines described on [ask].

Answer (score 2):

There are no such tools. The culprit is either extensive usage of **`QUERY`** formulas, **`IMPORT`** formulas, complex **`ARRAYFORMULA`** formulas with multiple virtual sub-calculations/sub-references and most likely it's done on a large unnecessary range eg a portion of blank cells is included in calculation which may have a negative impact on overall performance. It all depends on the individual scenario and best you can do is to find a pair of keen eyes which know where to track down deceleration and countermeasure it.